# Conflict between UTF-8 normalized-forms of encoding for accents

Tags: java, linux, encoding, utf-8, filesystems

I've got a bug with UTF-8 normalizations:

as far as I understood, there's (at least) two ways to write an 'é' in UTF-8 : `CC 81` and `C3 A9`.

[After a migration from Mac/OSX to a PC/Linux] I now have a conflict between the paths I store in my database and the actual file system structure, which prevents me from accessing correctly my files ...

With the help of [java.text.Normalizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html), I worked out that in the FS I've got:

```
NFD true
NFC false
NFKD true
NFKC false
```

while in the database (and from the keyboard), I have:

```
NFD false
NFC true
NFKD false
NFKC true
```

Which of these four normalized-forms shall I comply with?
How could I (automatically) fix the encoding of the filesystem directories?

---

**EDIT2**: the problem is not at all  what I though about at the beginning, hence everything below stroked out.

<strike>do you know if there is any rule (RFC ?) defining the handling of `file://` URLs?</strike>

My concern is about the accents,  <strike>I try to access a picture at</strike>

```
file:///other/Web/data/images/2005/2005-12-31 Fin d'ann&eacute;e/IMGP0012.JPG
```

but it doesnt' work, **EDIT**: of course it doesn't work with `&eacute` in URL ...

however, Gumbo's suggestion

```
file:///other/Web/data/images/2005/2005-12-31%20Fin%20d'ann%C3%A9e/IMGP0012.JPG
```

doesn't work either, but (Firefox->Copy Link Location)

```
file:///other/Web/data/images/2005/2005-12-31%20Fin%20d%27anne%CC%81e
```

is okay.

is there any standard way to access this data on the local filesystem, or shall I try all the available encoding ... ?

(my code is written in Java and I test it with FF 3.6)

Comment: You *are* aware of the `...né...` vs. `...ńe...` discrepancy?!

Comment: not sure what you are talking about, but in the first version of the question I had a funny bug with the accent of 'année'  moving by itself between the first and second e!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally 'normalized' (renamed) my file system directories, according to the names stored in the database, OSX messed everything up !

Answer (score 4):

You need to encode these characters with the [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1). Try this:

```
file:///other/Web/data/images/2005/2005-12-31%20Fin%20d'ann%C3%A9e/IMGP0012.JPG
```

Here `%C3%A9` represents the `é` in UTF-8 encoded. Maybe you need to change the character encoding if your application expects a different character encoding than UTF-8.

Comment: thanks for this `percent-encoding` remainder, I got confused with all these different encodings :)